# Catching exceptions thrown by Swagger

Tags: exception, swagger-ui

I'm new at fumbling with Swagger, so I might be asking a silly question. Is it in any way possible to prevent the site from crashing whenever it is "unable to read from api"?

My site is working most of the time, but if there for some reason is an api that is unreadable (or just unreachable) swagger just stop working. It still displays the api's it managed to reach, but all functionality is completely gone its not even able to expand a row.

To summarize:

How do I prevent swagger from crashing, when one or more API's is unreadable and returns something like this:

> Unable to read api 'XXXX' from path
>   http://example.com/swagger/api-docs/XXXX (server
>   returned undefined)

Below is my initialization of Swagger:

```
function loadSwagger() {
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    url: "/frameworks/swagger/v1/api.json",
    dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
    supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'],
    onComplete: function (swaggerApi, swaggerUi) {
        log("Loaded SwaggerUI");

        if (typeof initOAuth == "function") {

            initOAuth({
              clientId: "your-client-id",
              realm: "your-realms",
              appName: "your-app-name"
            });

        }
        $('pre code').each(function (i, e) {
            hljs.highlightBlock(e);
        });
    },
    onFailure: function (data) {
        log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
    },
    docExpansion: "none",
    sorter: "alpha"
});

$('#input_apiKey').change(function () {
    var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
    log("key: " + key);
    if (key && key.trim() != "") {
        log("added key " + key);
        window.authorizations.add("api_key", new ApiKeyAuthorization('api_key', key, 'header'));
    }
});

$('#apiVersionSelectID').change(function () {
    var sel = $('#apiVersionSelectID').val();
    window.swaggerUi.url = sel;
    $('#input_baseUrl').val(sel);
    $('#explore').click();
});

window.swaggerUi.load();
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a solution to this problem too but could not find one. Here is a quick hack i did to solve the problem. Hope it can be of help to someone who is having the same trouble.

In swagger-client.js Find the function error: function (response) {

I replaced the return api_fail with addApiDeclaration to make it draw the api with some limited information even when it fails. I send in a dummy api json object with the path set to "/unable to load ' + _this.url. I send in an extra parameter that can be true or false, where true indicates that this is a failed api.

Old code:

```
enter cerror: function (response) {
      _this.api.resourceCount += 1;
      return _this.api.fail('Unable to read api \'' +
      _this.name + '\' from path ' + _this.url + ' (server returned ' +response.statusText + ')');
    }
```

New code

```
 error: function (response) {
      _this.api.resourceCount += 1;                                
      return _this.addApiDeclaration(JSON.parse('{"apis":[{"path":"/unable to load ' + _this.url + '","operations":[{"nickname":"A","method":" "}]}],"models":{}}'), true);
    }
```

I modified the addApiDeclaration function in the same file to display a different message for a failed api by first adding  a secondary parameter to it called failed and then an if statement that check if failed is true and then change the name of the api to "FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE " + this.name. This adds the FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE text before the failed api.

Old code

```
 SwaggerResource.prototype.addApiDeclaration = function (response) {
  if (typeof response.produces === 'string')
    this.produces = response.produces;
  if (typeof response.consumes === 'string')
    this.consumes = response.consumes;
  if ((typeof response.basePath === 'string') && response.basePath.replace(/\s/g, '').length > 0)
    this.basePath = response.basePath.indexOf('http') === -1 ? this.getAbsoluteBasePath(response.basePath) : response.basePath;
  this.resourcePath = response.resourcePath;
  this.addModels(response.models);
  if (response.apis) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < response.apis.length; i++) {
      var endpoint = response.apis[i];
      this.addOperations(endpoint.path, endpoint.operations, response.consumes, response.produces);
    }
  }
  this.api[this.name] = this;
  this.ready = true;
  if(this.api.resourceCount === this.api.expectedResourceCount)
    this.api.finish();
  return this;
};
```

New code

```
SwaggerResource.prototype.addApiDeclaration = function (response, failed) {
  if (typeof response.produces === 'string')
    this.produces = response.produces;
  if (typeof response.consumes === 'string')
    this.consumes = response.consumes;
  if ((typeof response.basePath === 'string') && response.basePath.replace(/\s/g, '').length > 0)
    this.basePath = response.basePath.indexOf('http') === -1 ? this.getAbsoluteBasePath(response.basePath) : response.basePath;
  this.resourcePath = response.resourcePath;
  this.addModels(response.models);
  if (response.apis) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < response.apis.length; i++) {
      var endpoint = response.apis[i];
      this.addOperations(endpoint.path, endpoint.operations, response.consumes, response.produces);
    }
  }
  if (failed == true) {
      this.name = "FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE - " + this.name;
  }
  this.api[this.name] = this;
  this.ready = true;
  if(this.api.resourceCount === this.api.expectedResourceCount)
    this.api.finish();
  return this;
};
```